# Jsoup parsing with Android

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse html with `Jsoup` lib. However, I did not get what I want.
I want to bring to the screen of a mobile device the entire text of the tag `<pre>`

Please tell me, how do I get the text from web? How do I need to fix?

Web site: http://devanswers.ru/text.php

```
package com.example.devanswers;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView DevMainText;
    ImageView DevMainImage;
    MyTask DevMain;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DevMainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DevMainText);
        DevMainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DevMainImage);

        OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DevMain = new MyTask();
                DevMain.execute();
            }
        };

        DevMainImage.setOnClickListener(onClick);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            DevMainImage.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://devanswers.ru/text.php").get();
                Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("pre");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    DevMainText.setText((link.text()));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                DevMainText.setText("Error");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            DevMainImage.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never use the Jsoup before but what i can see from your code that you over write what in the DevMainText each time you get data from the page

so you should setText in your textview like this:

```
String maintext = "";
   for (Element link : links) {
    maintext += link.text() +"\n";
   }
DevMainText.setText(maintext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Infact the response is not wrapped in the `<pre>` tag. Its the browser who wraps the raw response in the `<pre>` tag when you view the source.

Instead of `doc.getElementsByTag("pre")` try `doc.getElementsByTag("body")`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the Android WebView component, if you want to display the entire page. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

You can easily parse the page using the URI class 
`Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://devanswers.ru/text.php");`and then display this in a WebView.